# Associate each enum case with a type in Swift

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to apply the dependency inversion principle to the UserDefaults and also make it as strong-typed as possible.

Suppose that I have the following enum:

```swift
enum LocalStorageKeys: String {
    case user
    case account
}
```

Then, I need a `LocalStorage` protocol:

```swift
protocol LocalStorage {
    func save(key: LocalStorageKeys, value: Any) throws
    func get(key: LocalStorageKeys) -> Any?
}
```

I know that we could use a generic both in save and get methods, but how could I implement it in a way that when using `localStorage.save(key: .user, value: user)`, it must be provided with the `User`, and only with the `User` type? Also, how could I do so the compiler can infer that `localStorage.get(.user)` is of type `User`?

In the end, I would like to protect myself from doing things like `localStorage.save(key: .user, value: someOtherThing)`

Thanks!

Comment: You can find many articles online on creating a property wrapper for UserDefaults which could be a good solution for you.

Comment: One of many possibilities is to completely drop the key-value API. Create an object with attributes, save it to UserDefaults as `Data` (e.g. JSON encoded).
Another possibility is to make the keys an internal type. The public API should be `saveUser(_ user: User)` and `getUser() -> User?`.

Comment: I dislike the property wrapper solution because it makes difficult to unit test any part of the code that relates with the User Defaults, as it uses them in  a singleton-way. (correct me if I'm wrong please)

Comment: Aren't `UserDefaults` a singleton anyway? What's the problem with using them as singleton?

Comment: Suppose that I have two different classes that have a dependency on User Defaults and I need to unit test them. When running the tests they may crash or not, depening on the order of execution. That's one of the reasons why I would like to isolate the User Defaults behind a protocol, to be able to mock the dependency in the tests.

Comment: Yes, but the property wrapper don't need to be part of that protocol, they are part of the implementation. The mock won't have property wrappers.

Comment: For unit tests related to UserDefaults there are many solutions, one is to not use UserDefaults.standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution based on how Apple does its serialisation is to have different key enumerations per type you want to be able to save.

First create a protocol that anything that can be saved (or got back) must adopt

```
protocol Saveable
{
    associatedtype Key: CodingKey
}
```

Any type that you want to be able to save must have a `Key` nested type that conforms to `CodingKey`. The latter is only so that I have a consistent way to extract a key as a string from an instance of `Key`.

Change your protocol as follows

```
protocol LocalStorage
{
    func save<T: Saveable>(value: T, for key: T.Key)
    func get<T: Saveable>(type: T.Type, key: T.Key) -> T?
}
```

If `T.Key` is an enum, whenever you save a value of type `T` you are automatically restricted to using the enum cases from `T.Key`. The reason I put `value` first is because it means that when you are typing a call to the function, by the time you get to `for:` the Xcode editor has already figured out what the allowable keys are and will give you a completion list to choose from.

Here is how you might implement `User`

```
struct User
{
    var name: String
}

extension User: Saveable
{
    enum Key: String, CodingKey
    {
        case user
        case otherUser
    }
}
```

In the above case, there are two allowed keys for storing a `User`.

And here is a stub implementation of a `LocalStorage`

```
struct StorageImplementation: LocalStorage
{
    func save<T: Saveable>(value: T, for key: T.Key)
    {
        print(key.stringValue)
    }

    func get<T: Saveable>(type: T.Type, key: T.Key) -> T?
    {
        print(key.stringValue)
        return nil
    }
}
```

And this is what calling it looks like

```
let user = User(name: "jeremy")
StorageImplementation().save(value: user, for: .otherUser) // prints otherUser
StorageImplementation().get(type: User.self, key: .user) // prints user
```

Comment: Do you think it's possible to bring it one step further and declare `get` as `getValue<T: Savable>(for key: T.Key) -> T?`? E.g., if I call `StorageImplementation().getValue(for: User.user)`, it's known at compile time that `User.user` is an instance of `User.Key`, so the compiler should be able to infer the return type as `User`. However, if I try to implement it, I get "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" on the call site.

Comment: I guess it's because some other than `User` type could declare `User.Key` as its `Key`, and the compiler can't guarantee that `T` is always `User`. The solution is not perfect, unfortunately. IMO it's not much better than the existing `UserDefaults` implementation, if you need to specify the return type for each key.